# Convert array Byte To Binary

Tags: java

please any one can help me to convert the ascciiText to binary such as 49 have binary 00110001 and 48 is 00110010 and so on
this is my code

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class encrption {

public static void main(String[] args){

     // INPUT: KeyText   (StrKey).
    // OUTPUT: Ciphertext (ConcatenatedData).
   //String ConcatenatedData; 


    // Read data from user.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Your PlainText");
    String StrValue = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Your KeyText ");
    String StrKey = in.nextLine();

  // Print the Concatenated Data.

 String ConcatenatedData = StrKey.concat(StrValue);
       System.out.println("the Concatenated Data is :"+ConcatenatedData);

  // Convering the Concatenated data to Ascii data.

 try { 
  byte[] asciiText = ConcatenatedData.getBytes("US-ASCII");


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asciiText)); 

}

 catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e)
     { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Please any one can help me to convert the  series of ascciiText to binary such as 49 have binary 00110001 and 48 is 00110010 and so on

> Configuration: encrption - JDK version 1.8.0_40

Enter Your PlainText
welcome
Enter Your KeyText 
123
the Concatenated Data is :123welcome
[49, 50, 51, 119, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101]

Process completed.

Comment: `Integer.toBinaryString()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `byte` doesn't provide any method for this you'll have to use `Integer`:

```
byte[] b = ...;//you're array
String binStr = "";

for(byte v : b)
    binStr += Integer.toBinaryString(v);
```

Or you could write your own method. Wouldn't be too difficult aswell:

```
String toBinary(byte b){
    char[] binArr = new char[8];

    //if a bit is 1, emplace '1' at the respective position in the array, else 0
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
        binArr[7 - i] = (b & (1 << i)) == 0 ? '0' : '1';

    return new String(binArr);
}
```

Comment: when adding this line[String binStr = Integer.toBinaryString(ascciiText)] gives to me this error   error: incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to int

Comment: the reason for this is pretty simple: `Integer.toBinaryString()` expects a numeric type as parameter, not an `Array`, as shown in the example. You'll have to iterate over the array and transform every single byte on its own

Comment: can you  do it for me

Answer (score 1):

Simialr on @Paul's solution but written another way.

```
String toBinary(byte b) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);

    for(int i = 7 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        sb.append((char) ('0' + ((b >> i) & 1));

    return sb.toString();
}
```